# fstab help, please

Tags: fstab

I can mount a drive on another Ubuntu server using this command line:

```
sudo mount -t cifs -o username=steve,password=UahDYXxyzzyjz4U8 //192.168.1.81/share /mnt/z
```

But for the life of me I can't figure out how to put this into fstab so that it is mounted on startup.  Everything I try gives me an error.

This is my most recent attempt:

```
//192.168.1.81/share /mnt/z cifs noserverinfo,nofail,username=steve,password=UahDYXxyzzyjz4U8,iocharset=utf8,sec=ntlm,vers=1.0  0  0
```

But I get this error:

```
mount error(95): Operation not supported
```

This is the samba.conf section for the shared drive (on another Ubuntu server):

```
[share]
   comment = Steve's Public folder
   path = /home/steve/share
   create mask=0777
   directory mask=0777
   read only = no
   browsable = yes
   guest ok = yes
   force group = steve
   force user = steve
   ntlm auth = true
```

Any assistance would be appreciated...

Comment: Please provide your OS/product/release details

Comment: Is the Samba server running the same version of Ubuntu as the desktop or something different? 

Comment: Thanks. They are both Ubuntu Desktop, (but I am using them as servers)

Comment: New comment because stack times out while I was editing the comment

The shared drive is on Ubuntu 18.04.6 LTS, the mounting computer is running Ubuntu 20.04.4 LTS.

I managed to find the offending option and get no error when eliminating "noserverinfo".

It mounts now, but I am having a permissions problem where I can't write to the mounted drive, so I am suspecting a problem in my samba.conf